# Move website to another server without FTP or SSH

Tags: typo3

I have a problem with an existing TYPO3 website. (9.5.13)
Unfortunately, I no longer have FTP or SSH access to this server. (Provider can no longer be contacted) I would therefore have to move this website to another server. I only have admin access to Typo3 website.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this without copying the files and the database to the new server.

Is there a possibility? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real good way if you don't have a proper access to the server.

For the database you could use the extension [phpmyadmin](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/phpmyadmin) or [t3adminer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3adminer)
but there is IMO no extension to download the content of the fileadmin (which will be a native feature of TYPO3 11 LTS).

However you could download at least all extensions of course.

Answer (score 0):

In former times, there were two extensions trying to implement a FTP client as backend-module. The one was "[Typo3 quixplorer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3quixplorer)", the other was "[Typo3 eXtplorer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3extplorer)"... Quixplorer is outdated (last update of extension in 2010), eXtplorer had its last update 2008...

**Both extensions have security issues! Be careful and remove them immediately after usage!**

Maybe you can find similar projects running in current web environments...

Answer (score 0):

You may build some php script to archive the whole fileadmin-folder, and make a database dump. which you can download from the server.

Or you use a script to contact the new server to transfer the data immideatly.

It's just a question how you can upload these scripts as TYPO3 does not allow the direct upload of executables.

Comment: Could be wrapped by a simple extension. Extension could be uploaded via extensionmanager (if it's not a composer-based instance)

Comment: hush. no hints for hackers who get access to an installation, but don't know much about TYPO3.

Comment: Hints for somebody having already maintainer access? I think then you have already lost...

Answer (score 0):

This is a really unfortunate situation, but you can copy the database and the files by using this extensions. Be aware: I haven't tested this extensions or took a look into the code and picked them by their description and README files. **Use them carefully and on your own risk!**

```
Note: In general the TYPO3 Security Team recommends to not use any 
extension that bundles database management tools on production TYPO3 
websites.
```

**Database:**
Use [EXT:adminer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3adminer) or [EXT:phpmyadmin](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/phpmyadmin) to download your database tables.

---

**Files:**
Install [EXT:commands](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/commands) or [EXT:additional_scheduler](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/additional_scheduler) to zip & download your files & folders.

---

**All in one solution:**
While researching I've found the extension [EXT:ns_backup](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ns_backup). Maybe you can us it to transfer the backup to cloud services like dropbox.